# Duplication of settings for multi-site django setup

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm using the same django codebase on multiple apps on heroku. My set up is using a git master branch and individual branches for each separate domain. However I'm struggling with the ideal solution of storing setting variables which are different for each app.

I was going down the route of storing them in environment variables, separate for each app on heroku. This would of been the ideal solution. However there are one or two admin functions which I currently only run locally in my app which needs to know the settings for each app. This means I'd have to store all the settings for each app in every apps environment. For instance:

instead of

```
site_email=blah@site.com
```

I'd end up with:

```
site1_email=blah@site1.com
site2_email=blah@site2.com
```

and so on...

I could do this but it just seems pretty messy to me. Are there any alternatives? I could rip out the offending functions and build them into their own app, but this seems alot of work just to hide app settings from each other.

Comment: You could create a separate python module with common settings and import settings from this module from within you settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

given the following app setup:

```
/Project/
    /app1/
    /app2/
    /project/ (the project app that gets auto created in Django 1.4+)
        /settings/
            __init__.py <- general site inspecific settings
            sitea.py <- site A's specific settings
            siteb.py <- site B's specific settings
```

inside `sitea.py` put Site specific settings (you can still use the `os.environ.get()` calls to use heroku stored settings).

```
# Default Django settings for project.
from project.settings import * 

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
STATIC_ROOT = ''
```

then in your heroku run/startup script do the equivalent of (I assume you'll be using gunicorn or some other production django server)

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=project.settings.sitea
```

### Update -  an example `Project/project/settings/production.py` file, note: all sensitive info reads from environment not from file.

```
from project.settings import *

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    ('Francis', 'francis@teamcolab.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DATABASE'),                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': os.environ.get('MYSQL_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('MYSQL_HOST'),                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': os.environ.get('MYSQL_PORT'),                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

REDIS = {
    'HOST' : os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST'),
    'PASSWORD' : os.environ.get('REDIS_PASSWORD', None),
    'PORT' : int(os.environ.get('REDIS_PORT', 6379)),
    'DB' : int(os.environ.get('REDIS_DB', 0)),
}

WEBSOCKET_URL = os.environ.get('WEBSOCKET_URL')

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['XX.com','production.XX.com','www.XX.com',]

SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.XX.com'

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.environ.get('MEDIA_ROOT')

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.environ.get('STATIC_ROOT')
```

Comment: I like this solution. Yes I'd lose the separation of code and configuration but least I'd keep my sanity and it's very straightforward. Yup heroku uses gunicorn. I could use a separate Procfile in each git branch to load the correct settings file. For the master branch which I run locally and needs to access the settings in both `sitea.py` and `siteb.py` would I need to refer to them seperatley in code? i.e. `site_email = settings.sitea.site_email`?

Comment: in code it would be normal: `from django.conf import settings` and `settings.site_email` depending on which site you were on, it would load that Site's email into that setting.

Comment: I see how that would work for one of the branches where I'd of specified an individual settings file `--settings=project.settings.sitea` but what about the master branch, which needs to access `site_email` for both `sitea.py` and `siteb.py`?

Comment: I'd create a `master.py` and treat it like I would any of the other branches: `python manage.py runserver --settings=project.settings.master` `settings.site_email` maybe have SITE_EMAIL be a `[]` for the master settings

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work but getting lots of errors such as `AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'` and errors regarding the secret_key not being set, when they are infact set in the `__init__.py`, Do I need to import anything into the `sitea.py` and `siteb.py` files?

Comment: yes the first line in those files should be: `from project.settings import * ` which should import EVERYTHING from the `__init__.py`

Comment: ok, I'll keep messing around with it, but i'm sure you've put me on the right track. thanks!

Comment: I uploaded a full sample production settings file from one of my apps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we do it at The Motley Fool.

We have multiple settings files, one for each environment.

We have a `defaults.py` settings file which is the 'stock' for all environments.

We have settings files for each environment: `testing.py`, `live.py` etc.

These contain the changes from default (or completely different settings as needed).

We use Fabric + an internal deployer to deploy the right settings file to the right environment.

We have a fabfile that looks like this (simplified):

```
@task @def test():
    """sets environment to test"""
    set_hosts(['testserver01.test.com', 'testserver02.test.com']) #servers to deploy to
    env.environment = 'testing'
```

We have an internal deployer that scripts the creation of the environment:

```
def setup():
    from fabric.api import cd, env
    with cd(env.checkout):
        env.run('python create_manage_script.py %s' % env.environment)
```

So when we deploy, here's what happens:

- User runs `fab {{environment}} deploy`
- Our deployer looks at the settings directory, and looks for a settings file that matches the environment name (testing/live/etc)
- The deployer sends the appropriate commands to fabric,
- Fabric deploys the code to that server and points the server to the correct settings file

It's important to note that we have three different environments (dev, test, live), and we have three different apps that use these three different environments.

Comment: thanks for your indepth answer. That's quite an interesting approach but I was hoping for a fairly simple solution though which takes advantage of heroku's environment variables, allowing me to separate code from configuration

Comment: Although thinking about it there probably isn't a simple solution...maybe taking your approach and having a local master settings file and then build a script which pushes the separate settings to each app is the only way